# Maintaining multi language store

Tags: php, magento-1.7, multilingual

I am new to magento. I have created one site with multi-language store.
One is in english while the other one is in italian.
Problem with italian store is, only half of the page is translated into italian. The rest is in english.

Can anyone help me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add translated words in a csv file located at app/locale/en_(language)/(filename).csv